# Disregarding more particular ISA's, is it incorrect to use char argc instead of int argc

Tags: c++, c

For example, on an x86 architecture, where chars are represented as 1 byte, as long as you don't have more than 127 or 255 (depending on how its represented) arguments passed on the stack, shouldn't this be possible. Could this cause issues with alignment for the stack since argv would be 8 bytes to argc's 1 byte vs 8 bytes to argc's 4 bytes?

Is this incorrect, or does it depend on implementation and application

```
int main(char argc, char **argv)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are the results of those trials?

Comment: @Fe2O3 Trial and error is not the best way to learn a language(specially C++). Instead a book or some other authoritative source should be used.

Comment: @JasonLiam Lots of SO questions have been downvoted (hammered) (particularly in the past few hours) for failure to demonstrate the OP has done any research on their own... I think my question is fair...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I have tried compiling it with gcc, which doesn't give me any issues and works on my ISA, but I was more concerned with whether it was incorrect or not, but its not black and white like that apparently. More like just system dependent.

Comment: One issue may be occur the program is run with [0] + 127+ parameters. (Ridiculous?) My suspicion is that the "argc" as a signed one-byte value could be evaluated as negative thereby messing with conditionals like `if( argc > 2 ) ...` Just speculating..

Comment: @Fe2O3 but as long as I don't reach 127+ (if its represented as a signed 1 byte int) arguments for main, then I wouldn't need to worry about the edge cases right? I'm not actually implementing this, just trying to expand on what I know about C.

Comment: It would have worked fine under K&R C, which assumed an ABI with no arguments narrower than `int`.  But, since AFAIK there *are* ABI's which do pass plain chars as themselves and don't conflate them with `int`, `char argc` is, yes, absolutely incorrect.

Comment: @Anaspiringdeveloper We use human language with the hope/expectation that most/all will have a "shared" understanding of grammars, meanings and idioms. While it is good to explore/experiment, there are enough boggling ideas/algorithms to keep one learning/growing for years. Others with broader knowledge than mine have answered. My recommendation is to follow conventions and learn idioms proven to work. Don't make your readers scratch their head asking, "... but... why?" All good `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it incorrect to use `char argc` instead of `int argc`

Maybe.

C allows various argument parameter sets with `main()` with "... or in some other implementation-defined manner.".  `char argc` would not be outright non-conforming as it *may* be allowed on that implementation, but certainly not a portable usage as `... main(char argc, ...)` is not regularly allowed.  If an implementation allows `... main(char argc, ...)`, it is OK, else it it not.

---

> Could this cause issues with alignment for the stack since `argv` would be 8 bytes to `argc`'s 1 byte vs 8 bytes to `argc`'s 4 bytes?

Detail: `argc` is not certainly 4-bytes as an `int` may differ from 4 bytes.  Pointers are not certainly 8 bytes.

If `... main(char argc, ...)` was valid for a given implementation, there is no alignment issue.  If `... main(char argc, ...)` is not valid, then alignment is not the concern as that function signature is not valid.

---

> Is this incorrect, or does it depend on implementation and application

If the (compiler) implementation allows it it is OK, else it is not correct.  It is not depend on the application, but dependent on the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

For it to be meaningful to ask whether some code is correct or incorrect, there must be a set of rules to judge it against. The C standard alone is voluntary; no person or product is automatically required to conform to it. If your employer or customer wants you to produce C code that is portable according to the C standard, then that is a rule we can use to judge, and then it is incorrect to declare `main` as `int main(char argc, char **argv)`, as the behavior would not be defined by the C standard. It might work in some C implementations and fail in others.

In Application Binary Interfaces (ABIs) commonly used in the IA-32 (“x86”) architecture or the Intel 64 architecture (“x86-64”), this would not cause a stack alignment issue because both arguments would be passed in registers. If you get it to compile (GCC 12.2 will, Apple Clang 11.0 will not), I suspect it will “work.”

With an ABI that passed arguments on the stack, this could indeed mess up the stack.

Comment: Shouldn't `char` be promoted to `int` in case of passing on stack? The same as char parameter in variadic functions, e.g. `char c; printf("%i", c)`

Comment: @dimich: Promotions occur when calling functions without prototypes (that is functions declared without indicating their parameter types), and the function definitions must define their parameters to match the promoted types. `int main(char argc, char **argv)` would not match a call using `int` for the first argument.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Did you intentionally put `char **argv[]` in your int main in your answer, or was that a mistake?

Comment: @Anaspiringdeveloper: Just my habit of using `char *argv[]` colliding with trying to match OP’s `char **argv`. Thanks, fixed.